# Is it possible to add border to image in GitHub markdown?

Tags: html, github, markdown

I need to add border to the image in GitHub README.md file. This is how image should be embeded:

```
![GitHub Logo](/images/logo.png)
```

I have tried to wrap image with the table:

```
|--------------------------------|
|![GitHub Logo](/images/logo.png)|
```

but it is not possible to create table without header.

I have also tried to include image as html tag:

```
<img src="/images/logo.png" style="border: 1px solid black" />
```

but without success. Is there any way how to do this?

Comment: Might not be possible any longer with just markdown, you used to be able to add things like "``` | width=100```" just before the closing parenthesis.

Comment: And if you inspect the ```<img>``` element in the browser, you'll see that GitHub replaces your style="" with ```style="max-width:100%;"```.  Thus preventing you from putting a style="" attribute on your img tag.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

It's hacky and not always pretty, but surround the image with a `<kbd>` tag.

## Before

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtiyS.png">
```

## After

```
<kbd>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtiyS.png">
</kbd>
```

And it renders like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

**Surrounding the *markdown* image syntax might not work for some markdown implementations.**  If the following does not work

```
<kbd>![alt-text](https://example.com/image.png)</kbd>
```

Try embedding the image as an HTML `<img>` tag instead

```
<kbd><img src="https://example.com/image.png" /></kbd>
```

Comment: "On GitHub, for example, the following will just render as weird looking text" — which makes this answer completely irrelevant, as this question is precisely about GitHub.

Comment: @skalee The answer works for github just fine.  All I’m saying there is that you need to use the correct syntax.

Comment: it does work on github. You need to close the `img` tag though.

Comment: Looks really nice. Had just a simple border in mind, going back with some rounded edges, elevation effect and a shadow around the image.

Comment: This worked for me on our gitlab instance. +1

Comment: This is currently working fine on Github without using the img tag

Comment: Thanks for the update @JohnRoe, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Can someone explain why this is hacky?

Comment: @TimoErnst I originally called it hacky just because it's a bit of a strange use of the `kbd` element.  The element is intended to be used with text to denote keyboard input, which is why the default styling in most browsers makes it look like a keyboard key.  So it's not guaranteed that all browsers or site CSS styles will do something reasonable when `kbd` wraps an image instead of a small amount of text.  So far it's been okay for me though :)

Answer (score 38):

Here on StackExchange sites, I like to use the "quote" markup `>` for this purpose.

For example:

```
> [![screenshot][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtiyS.png
```

renders like this:

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 31):

The way I do this on GitLab is using a table like so:

```
| ![Alt name of image](/path-to-image.png) |
|-|
```

This is similar to @kesadae11's answer but in order to make it work in GitLab, the additional pipe characters are needed.

Comment: This also worked for me with VSCode's markdown preview, while @kesadae11's answer did not.

Answer (score 23):

You can use `<table>` tag to create tables without header.

```
<table><tr><td>
    <img src="/images/logo.png" />
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the padding inside the table cells?

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to use table's first cell for it.

Code:

```
|![pictureAliasName](pathOfPicture/pictureName.png)|
-
```

The `-` character is important in the code.

You can see the result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pypso.png) .

Answer (score 3):

I often do like this in GitHub comments.
(Images can be HTML tags or markdown, so some line breaks may be necessary.)

```markdown
<!-- No end tag -->
<kbd> image

| image
|-

label_text
|-
image

image | image | image
-|-|-

<!-- with `kbd` for White background images -->
<kbd> image | <kbd> image | <kbd> image
-|-|-
```

```
Before | After
-|-
image | image
```

```markdown
<!-- Template with details tag -->
<details>
<summary>Screenshots</summary>

Before | After
-|-
image | image
</details>
```

```markdown
<!-- Vertical alignment -->
<table><tbody valign="top">
<td>

image
<td>

image
</table>

<!-- only Row -->
<table>
<tr>
<td>

image
<td>

image
<tr valign="top">
<td>

image
<td>

image
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the following and it worked for me just fine

```
<img src="image-20220820124005006.png" alt="image-20220820124005006" style="border: 3px solid red" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a "readme.md" file that includes a chart showing different colors and their codes using the RGB system. To highlight the color white, I added a border around it.

Here's the solution I used:

```
<img style="border: .5px solid;" src="https://placehold.co/100x50/FFFFFF/FFFFFF">
```

Comment: This does not work in README files on GitHub.

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src='src' alt="des" style="border: 2px solid  gray; border-radius:15px">
```

Enjoy Coding :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not work in README files on GitHub.

Answer (score -7):

Another way is to provide the border yourself in an image editing tool and upload that.